# Dúvida Query Linha - Oracle

Tags: query, oracle, oracle11g

Na query abaixo está saindo dessa forma.

> ```
> Unidade        Ordem_Compra   CNPJ           Aprovador
> Sim Boavista     29021         155454878787    Ivan
> Sim Boavista     29021         155454878787    Romel
> ```

A dúvida é: Como faço para deixar em uma linha só dessa forma?

> ```
> Unidade        Ordem_Compra   CNPJ           Aprovador
> Sim Boavista     29021         155454878787    Ivan,Romel
> ```

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.nm_fantasia_estab Unidade,
                c.nr_ordem_compra Ordem_Compra,
                g.cd_cgc CNPJ_Fornecedor,
                g.ds_razao_social Razão_Social_Fornecedor,
                NVL(SUM(v.vl_vencimento),0) Valor_Total_da_Ordem,
                SUBSTR(tasy.obter_nome_pf(f.cd_pessoa_fisica),1,255) Aprovador,
                c.DT_APROVACAO Data_Aprovação
  FROM tasy.ordem_compra c
  LEFT JOIN tasy.estabelecimento e ON e.cd_estabelecimento = c.cd_estabelecimento
  LEFT JOIN tasy.pessoa_juridica g ON g.cd_cgc = c.cd_cgc_fornecedor
  LEFT JOIN tasy.ordem_compra_venc v ON v.nr_ordem_compra = c.nr_ordem_compra
  LEFT JOIN TASY.PROCESSO_APROV_COMPRA r ON r.nr_documento = c.nr_ordem_compra
  LEFT JOIN tasy.pessoa_fisica f ON f.cd_pessoa_fisica = r.cd_pessoa_fisica
 WHERE e.cd_estabelecimento NOT IN(1,23)
   AND r.ie_aprov_reprov IN('A','P')
   AND (r.cd_pessoa_fisica IN(623440,185666,257322) OR r.cd_pessoa_fisica IS NULL)
   AND c.nr_ordem_compra = 29021
 GROUP BY e.nm_fantasia_estab, c.nr_ordem_compra, g.cd_cgc, g.ds_razao_social,c.DT_APROVACAO,SUBSTR(tasy.obter_nome_pf(f.cd_pessoa_fisica),1,255)
 ORDER BY c.nr_ordem_compra;
```

Comment: Você está utilizando o Oracle 11g?

Comment: sim @PedroPaulo

Comment: Tenta usar a função WM_CONCAT, acredito que ela faz o que você precisa